# Is it possible to check duplicated images

Tags: windows

I have received thousand of images from my client and found that some images are duplicated. It was time wasting for doing the visual checking.

I want to ask if there any software would help to check duplicated images, thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. If you're looking for an existing program, try SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

yea, there's one tool for windows, i heard of.. named, "Dup Detector" .. it facilitates by cheking the images in a folder, pixel by pixel and tells about all duplicates that exist in that folder.. OR you may also select one to find duplicate for..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [Image Comparer](http://www.bolidesoft.com/imagecomparer.html) tool. It works with the dozens of image formats including RAW ones. I think it should help you

Answer (score 0):

Google search lead me to these four pages. I will let you shift through these to find a product you like. In case you want to look at more sources I've prepared you a link from www.googleitfor.me:

GoogleItForMe Link:

```
http://googleitfor.me/?q=find+duplicate+images
```

Other Links

```
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-ways-to-find-duplicate-image-files-on-your-computer-windows/
http://download.cnet.com/Find-Duplicate-Images/3000-12511_4-75622234.html
http://www.ashisoft.com/duplicate-images-finder.htm
http://www.mindgems.com/products/VS-Duplicate-Image-Finder/VSDIF-About.htm
```

Comment: So which one you recommend?

Comment: Personally out of the ones that are there I agree with the bottom post. Dup Detector looks to be the best, and pretty easy to use.That or DupliFinder. I don't typically like to present my opinion unless asked. You will really need to work with the application to know what works for you and meets your needs 100%

Answer (score 0):

The images are in general the same picture (size, format, extension) in distinct folders? If yes, in the internet have many softwares to find duplicate archives in your pc.
Please! check [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tools-for-getting-rid-of-duplicate-files/1248) and [this](http://lifehacker.com/392033/compare-and-delete-duplicate-images-with-duplifinder)

But if you need a software with complex heuristics the job is very hard.